# How to use regex when a substring is not unique?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string

```
.....text .....person id: 2938 date of birth......text ....  
.....................person id: 238949 date of birth........
.......person id: 5555 date of birth..........................
...........person id: 232229 date of birth........
```

I need to get the substring that appears between the **third** occurence of the work `person id` and `date of birth`, i.e. `5555`

How can I parse it?

Comment: where's your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
(?:person id:.*?){3}(\d+)\s+date of birth
```

This will match:

- `person id:` followed by zero or more characters, non-greedily, repeated 3 times
- one or more digits, captured in group 1
- one or more whitespace characters
- `date of birth`

Of course, if there are many such occurrences like this (say 6 such similar records) it will actually match the number *every third* occurrence of `person id:`.